# Create table to show changes in separate columns

Tags: date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, lag

I have a table like:

| ID | NAME | CURRENT_DATE | ORDER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | NULL | 2023-01-01 | 1 |
| 5 | JESSICA | 2023-02-01 | 2 |
| 5 | JAMES | 2023-02-04 | 3 |
| 5 | NULL | 2023-02-15 | 7 |
| 12 | NULL | 2023-02-05 | 3 |
| 12 | JOSH | 2023-02-24 | 9 |
| 12 | ALEX | 2023-02-17 | 5 |

I would like to query this data to show changes in name per ID and show the dates that they were changed.

Basically I would like my query to produce a table like:

| ID | NAME | FROM_DATE | TO_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | NULL | 2023-01-01 | 22023-02-01 |
| 5 | JESSICA | 2023-02-01 | 2023-02-04 |
| 5 | JAMES | 2023-02-04 | 2023-02-15 |
| 5 | NULL | 2023-02-15 | 2023-04-09 |
| 12 | NULL | 2023-02-05 | 2023-02-17 |
| 12 | ALEX | 2023-02-17 | 2023-02-24 |
| 12 | JOSH | 2023-02-24 | 2023-04-09 |

Where the final TO_DATE value for the latest ID is today's date. The order column in the original table refers to the order in which the record appeared in the table

So far I have:

```
SELECT ID, LAG(NAME) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CURRENT_DATE) AS NAME, LAG(CURRENT_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ORDER) AS FROM_DATE, CURRENT_DATE AS TO_DATE
FROM MY_TABLE
```

But this is showing NULL in the from_date column for records where the first NAME value is NULL and I am not sure how to end the to_date with today's date when there are no records that come after.

Comment: You need to use the LEAD function on the CURRENT_DATE  to get the end date for each row (end date is the current date of the next, lead, row)

Answer (score 0):

If you data has no duplicates you can can use LEAD

```
with data (ID, NAME, event_DATE, _ORDER) as (
    select * from values
        (5, NULL, '2023-01-01'::date, 1),
        (5, 'JESSICA', '2023-02-01'::date, 2),
        (5, 'JAMES', '2023-02-04'::date, 3),
        (5, NULL, '2023-02-15'::date, 7),
        
        (12, NULL, '2023-02-05'::date, 3),
        (12, 'ALEX', '2023-02-17'::date, 5),
        (12, 'JOSH', '2023-02-24'::date, 9)
)
select 
    id
    ,name
    ,event_DATE as from_date
    ,lead(event_DATE,1,CURRENT_DATE)over(partition by id order by current_date)  as lag_event_DATE
from data
order by 1,3;
```

gives:

| ID | NAME | FROM_DATE | LAG_EVENT_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | null | 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 |
| 5 | JESSICA | 2023-02-01 | 2023-02-04 |
| 5 | JAMES | 2023-02-04 | 2023-02-15 |
| 5 | null | 2023-02-15 | 2023-03-09 |
| 12 | null | 2023-02-05 | 2023-02-17 |
| 12 | ALEX | 2023-02-17 | 2023-02-24 |
| 12 | JOSH | 2023-02-24 | 2023-03-09 |

if you have rows that span many ranges, you ether want to deduplicate the data before or after. So a simple single lead it is easier to clean-up on the before path, but skip any row where the LAG is the same as the this row.

```
with data (ID, NAME, event_DATE, _ORDER) as (
    select * from values
        (5, NULL, '2023-01-01'::date, 1),
        (5, 'JESSICA', '2023-02-01'::date, 2),
        (5, 'JAMES', '2023-02-04'::date, 3),
        (5, NULL, '2023-02-15'::date, 7),
        
        (12, NULL, '2023-02-05'::date, 3),
        (12, 'ALEX', '2023-02-17'::date, 5),
        (12, 'JOSH', '2023-02-24'::date, 9),

        (13, NULL, '2023-02-05'::date, 3),
        (13, NULL, '2023-02-06'::date, 4),
        (13, 'ALEX', '2023-02-17'::date, 5),
        (13, 'JOSH', '2023-02-24'::date, 9),
        (13, 'JOSH', '2023-02-25'::date, 10)

)
select
    *
    ,lag(name,1,'XXX_NEVER_MATCH')over(partition by id order by current_date) as lag_name
    ,LAG_NAME<>NAME as l2
    ,NAME is null AND lag_name is not null as l3
    ,NAME is not null and lag_name is null as l4
from data
QUALIFY l2 or l3 or l4
order by 1,3;
```

gives leading edges we want, so that can be feed into the first algo:

```
with data (ID, NAME, event_DATE, _ORDER) as (
    select * from values
        (5, NULL, '2023-01-01'::date, 1),
        (5, 'JESSICA', '2023-02-01'::date, 2),
        (5, 'JAMES', '2023-02-04'::date, 3),
        (5, NULL, '2023-02-15'::date, 7),
        
        (12, NULL, '2023-02-05'::date, 3),
        (12, 'ALEX', '2023-02-17'::date, 5),
        (12, 'JOSH', '2023-02-24'::date, 9),

        (13, NULL, '2023-02-05'::date, 3),
        (13, NULL, '2023-02-06'::date, 4),
        (13, 'ALEX', '2023-02-17'::date, 5),
        (13, 'JOSH', '2023-02-24'::date, 9),
        (13, 'JOSH', '2023-02-25'::date, 10)

)
select 
    id
    ,name
    ,event_DATE as from_date
    ,lead(event_DATE,1,CURRENT_DATE)over(partition by id order by current_date)  as lag_event_DATE
from (
    select
        *
        ,lag(name,1,'XXX_NEVER_MATCH')over(partition by id order by current_date) as lag_name
        ,LAG_NAME<>NAME as l2
        ,NAME is null AND lag_name is not null as l3
        ,NAME is not null and lag_name is null as l4
    from data
    QUALIFY l2 or l3 or l4
)
order by 1,3;
```

giving:

| ID | NAME | FROM_DATE | LAG_EVENT_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | null | 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 |
| 5 | JESSICA | 2023-02-01 | 2023-02-04 |
| 5 | JAMES | 2023-02-04 | 2023-02-15 |
| 5 | null | 2023-02-15 | 2023-03-09 |
| 12 | null | 2023-02-05 | 2023-02-17 |
| 12 | ALEX | 2023-02-17 | 2023-02-24 |
| 12 | JOSH | 2023-02-24 | 2023-03-09 |
| 13 | null | 2023-02-05 | 2023-02-17 |
| 13 | ALEX | 2023-02-17 | 2023-02-24 |
| 13 | JOSH | 2023-02-24 | 2023-03-09 |